# Importing a value using joins in Cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created a VPC stack which is exporting values such as VPC id, private and public subnet group. I am trying to build a string using short hand notations of `ImportValue, Join and Ref`. Any help is appreciated for making this expression work.

```
MyDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Subnets available for the RDS DB Instance
      SubnetIds: !ImportValue !Join [ '-', [ !Ref VPCStackName, 'private-subnets' ]]
      Tags:
      - Key: Service
        Value: !Ref ResourceTag
```

I am getting error which is obvious:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 87, column 29)
```

Tried things such as:

```
MyDBSubnetGroup:
        Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
        Properties:
          DBSubnetGroupDescription: Subnets available for the RDS DB Instance
          SubnetIds: !ImportValue
            - Fn::Join
              - '-'
              - - !Ref VPCStackName
              - 'vpcid'
          Tags:
          - Key: Service
            Value: !Ref ResourceTag
```

No luck!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html):

> Similarly, the ImportValue function can't include `Ref` or `GetAtt` functions that depend on a resource.

and:

> You can't use the short form of `!ImportValue` when it contains a `!Sub`.

(because it results in invalid YAML)

If `VPCStackName` is a parameter and you are exporting comma separated values, you can do the following:

```yaml
MyDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Subnets available for the RDS DB Instance
      SubnetIds:
        Fn::Split: # Split to get a list of strings
          - ","
          - Fn::ImportValue: # Use full function name
              !Sub "${VPCStackName}-private-subnets" # Substitute parameter
      Tags:
      - Key: Service
        Value: !Ref ResourceTag
```

Comment: Getting error: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must be a string or a function that returns a string`

Comment: What is `VPCStackName` is your template?

Comment: It's an input parameter to the template.

Comment: Can you share the full template in a gist?

Comment: It's resolved now. I had another invalid ImportValue in the template. Fixing that resolved the issue. Thanks!! :-)

Comment: It's referring the parameter correctly@jogold. However, when I'm trying to create a stack on AWS, I'm getting error `Value of property SubnetIds must be of type List of String`. How can I provide this value as List of Strings rather than a string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192642/discussion-between-krishna-kuntala-and-jogold).

Comment: For anyone trying this answer, don't forget the colon after `Fn::ImportValue`.  I did and it didn't work!